# Why does Amazon S3 evaluates bucket policy even when requester is the bucket owner?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

From [Example 1 (How Amazon S3 Authorizes a Request for a Bucket Operation)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-auth-workflow-bucket-operation.html):

> 2. In the bucket context, Amazon S3 reviews the bucket policy to determine if the requester has permission to perform the operation. Amazon S3 authorizes the request.

What is the need for evaluating bucket policy when the requester is the bucket owner (request made using root credentials) ?

If I'm the bucket owner, shouldn't it implicitly mean that I'll always have the permissions to perform any operation on the bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say company XYZ follows an SOP that every developer who needs a bucket in S3 should write/request to the infra guy sitting in his cabin, looking at monitors.

But should that infra guy have access to dev's content in their...???

Another example...

If you have rented your house out to me.
It doesn't mean you have the right to look into my wardrobe ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually possible to store objects in a bucket that are *not* accessible by the bucket owner. This often happens when one account stores objects in another account's bucket. (I know, sounds weird, doesn't it!)

That's why it's a good idea to use the `bucket-owner-full-control` ACL when copying files.

See: [S3 Bucket Owner Access](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-owner-access/)